# ASP.net IIS execute application RunAs the requester

Tags: asp.net, iis

Can I execute a service or executable (notepad.exe) from ASP.net IIS and this executable is running as the requester (client)?
for example:
John and Ada is 2 different clients and they have domain accounts.
IIS on Webserver have (notepad.exe).
when John request a Page on the IIS the notepad will runAs "John"
when Ada request a Page on the IIS the notepad will runAs "Ada"
is that applicable or note?

Answer (score 1):

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: after using impersonation the displayed user in task manager is :Application Pool Name , not the client who requested the page.